# Should I return 0 or 1 for successful function?

Tags: c, boolean

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error handling in C code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385975/error-handling-in-c-code)
>   [What return value should you use for a failed function call in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116480/what-return-value-should-you-use-for-a-failed-function-call-in-c)

I always use 0, but its not really readable in `if`, `while`, etc.

Should I return 1? Why main function `return 0` for success?

Comment: The linked question was closed.

Comment: @AdamBernier: As a duplicate.  It had some highly relevant answers.

Comment: @Oli: it doesn't seem appropriate that the other question was closed as a duplicate (maybe I'm just not seeing it). Nevertheless I agree with closing that one and this one: The questions do seem too open-ended for this particular website.

Comment: This answer depends on whether you want to return error codes, as opposed to true or false. Usually when having multiple return error codes, 0 is success and other values represent errors. I suppose people use 0 as success and nonzero for failure to remain consistent.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

It's defined by the C standard as `0` for success (credits go to hvd).

[But](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html)

> For greater portability, you can use the macros `EXIT_SUCCESS` and
>   `EXIT_FAILURE` for the conventional status value for success and
>   failure, respectively. They are declared in the file `stdlib.h`.

(I'm talking about the value returned to the OS from *main*, *exit* or similar calls)

As for your function, return what you wish and makes code more readable, as long as you keep it that way along your programs.

Comment: 0 always means success, but other exit codes are also permitted to mean success depending on the system.

Comment: @hvd That's not true. The values of `EXIT_SUCCESS` & `EXIT_FAILURE` are not defined in the C standard.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall `EXIT_SUCCESS` might have some other value than 0, but even then, `return 0;` *also* means success.

Comment: @hvd Don't you mean *only* then? If `EXIT_FAILURE` is `0`, then `return 0;` denotes failure.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall `EXIT_FAILURE` is not allowed to be 0, because returning 0 from main *always* means success.

Comment: @hvd: Indeed, this is implied in C99, 7.20.4.3.5.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall From the C standard: "Finally, control is returned to the host environment. If the value of status is zero or EXIT_SUCCESS, an implementation-defined form of the status successful termination is returned." (This is part of the description of the `exit` function, using the same codes.)

Comment: @hvd Nice, did not know that.

Answer (score 24):

The reason why `main` use `0` for success is that it is used as the exit code of the application to the operating system, where `0` typically means success and `1` (or higher) means failure. (Of course, you should always use the predefined macros `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE`.)

Inside an application, however, it's more natural to use zero for failure and non-zero for success, as the return value can directly be used in an `if` as in:

```
if (my_func())
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: "Inside an application, however, it's more natural to use zero for failure and non-zero for success, as the return value can directly be used in an if as in:" I would strongly argue against this, just putting a "!" not only solves the issue, but, it's much more clear and standard to ALWAYS return 0 for success. If the operative system follows it, c standard functions follows it, most of code in the internet follows it, It will confuse the reader.

Comment: @Santropedro: However, all functions that return data (like `malloc`, `fopen`, `fgets`, etc. ) return zero for failure and non-zero for success.

Comment: functions that return POINTERS, of course, return a non-zero POINTER on success, and NULL on failure. but most POSIX API calls that return an `int` status code return ZERO on SUCCESS, and other values on FAILURE. eg. `int fclose()`